# Best way to get the set of unique fields in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, say you have a table named **person**, with the following structure:

```
    Table "public.person"
      Column       |       Type        |                      Modifiers                      
-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------
 id                | integer           | not null default nextval('person_id_seq'::regclass)
 first_name        | character varying | not null
 last_name         | character varying | not null
 birthday          | date              | 
Indexes:
    "person_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

How would you find the unique set of first names?

By 'unique set' I mean this:

```
   Aaron
   Abbie
   Adam
   ...
```

Rather than this:

```
   Aaron
   Aaron
   Abbie
   Abbie
   Abbie
   Adam
   ...
```

My question is fairly similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20036771/postgresql-fastest-way-of-getting-the-set-of-unique-values-in-one-column-or-a-la), but I feel that question was quite specific to a particular person's use case and also did not get many answers - so I'd like to reopen the topic here.

My intuition would be to use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (first_name) first_name FROM person ORDER BY first_name;
```

Comment: Can you link to an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that reproduces the problem? When I tried reproducing on my own database the query worked perfectly.

Comment: You don't need `distinct on()` a plain `distinct` is enough `select distinct first_name from person;`

Comment: @Mureinik I've been unable to reproduce the problem in an SQLFiddle. There may be a deeper issue with my database... Running `SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY first_name` returns results for multiple people named Abbie, such as  **Abbie Smith**, **Abbie  Jones**, however `SELECT * FROM person WHERE first_name='Abbie'` returns just one result for **Abbie Smith**... This may warrant a new question.

Comment: Probably trailing spaces in the name. Try `select * from person where trim(first_name) = 'Abbie'` (and consequently `distinct trim(first_name)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this was the problem! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to eliminate duplicate rows do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_NAME FROM PERSON;
```

Or if you want to aggregate some fields:

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME, COUNT(1) CNT FROM PERSON GROUP BY FIRST_NAME;
```